# Showing warning to end user through postgres trigger without aborting transaction

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to **validate** one field through **postgres trigger**.

If targeted field has value in **decimals**,i need to through a **warning** but allowing the user to **save** the record.

I tried with options

```
RAISE EXCEPTION,RAISE - USING
```

but it's throwing **error on UI** and transaction is aborted.

I tried with options

```
RAISE NOTICE,RAISE WARNING
```

through which **warning is not shown** and record is simply saved.

It would be great if any one help on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `client_min_messages` to a level that'll show `NOTICE`s and `WARNING`s. You can do this:

- At the transaction level with `SET LOCAL`
- At the session level with `SET`
- At the user level with `ALTER USER`
- At the database level with `ALTER DATABASE`
- Globally in `postgresql.conf`

You must then check for messages from the server after running queries and display them to the user or otherwise handle them. How to do that depends on the database driver you're using, which you haven't specified. PgJDBC? libpq? other?

Note that raising a notice or warning will *not* cause the transaction to pause and wait for user input. You really don't want to do that. Instead `RAISE` an `EXCEPTION` that aborts the transaction. Tell the user about the problem, and re-run the transaction if they approve it, possibly with a flag set to indicate that an exception should not be raised again.

It would be technically possible to have a PL/Perlu, PL/Pythonu, or PL/Java trigger pause execution while it asked the client via a side-channel (like a TCP socket) to approve an action. It'd be a really bad idea, though.